# How do I use setw in C++ to align/format text in the console

Tags: c++

I'm I have a problem with trying to format the appearance of my code correctly. Sorry if this is a dumb question, but I'm really new to all of this.

I have this snippet here:

```
cout << "Thank you for your business!\n";
cout << endl << endl << endl;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
cout << "Sub-total:" << setw(11)   << "$" << SubTotal << endl;
cout << "+Sales Tax:" << setw(12)  << "$" << SalesTax << endl;
cout << "-Discount:" << setw(13)   << "$" << Discount << endl;
cout << "+Shipping:" << setw(13)   << "$" << ShippingCost << " (shipping to " << Destination << ")" << endl;
cout << "=Total:" << setw(14)      << "$" << Total << endl;
```

So what I'm trying to do, is make it output so it looks like this:

[image]

Notice how all the $ signs and decimal points are lined up. I'm kinda lost and I really don't know how to do that, so I was hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction. All I know is that it can be done with the these commands:

```
setprecision
fixed
setw
```

I thought I could just line it up in the editor, but when I enter different numbers, it gets all uneven.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
cout << "Thank you for your business!\n";
cout << endl << endl << endl;
cout << fixed;
cout << setprecision(2);
cout << setw(13) << left << "Sub-total:" << "$" << setw(8) << right << SubTotal << endl;
cout << setw(13) << left << "+Sales Tax:" << "$" << setw(8) << right << SalesTax << endl;
cout << setw(13) << left << "-Discount:" << "$" << setw(8) << right << Discount << endl;
cout << setw(13) << left << "+Shipping:" << "$" << setw(8) << right << ShippingCost << " (shipping to " << Destination << ")" << endl;
cout << setw(13) << left << "=Total:" << "$" << setw(8) << right << Total << endl;
```

The issue with your code was that you were setting the width of the "$". The `setw()` function sets the width of the element directly after it, in your case, the "$". Also, it was defaulting to a right justified manner, so you're giving the "$" these variable lengths and then pushing the characters to the rightmost of the space you gave it. You could tell by, if you changed *your* code to all `setw()` of a uniform number, say `setw(10)`, you'll notice the number of white spaces between the ":" character and "$" of every line is exactly 9. What you wanted was a specific width directly *before* the "$". Luckily you have text just before the "$" we'll call the first element, so we can set that to a permanent number of characters with the `setw()` function.

With that, my solution sets the width of the first element. That way they end at the same place always, and the next character (the "$") guaranteed appears after the space reserved for the first element. The second `setw()` is a little harder to recognize. If you look at your image example though, you'll notice that it's actually the numbers that have the permanent width, so it's just a matter of counting the number of characters of the largest number and setting the width of all the numbers to that, and of course, there's space between the "$" and the numbers of smaller length which hints towards right justification.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd create a small class (or struct) to hold each item in the output, and handle the formatting for an item:

```
struct item { 
    std::string label;
    double amount;
    std::string note;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, item const &i) { 
        os << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed;
        os << std::setw(15) << std::left << i.label 
           << " $" << std::right << std::setw(8) << i.amount;
        if (!i.note.empty())
            os << " (" << i.note << ")";
        return os;
    }
};
```

With that in place, it's just a matter of creating the items in the correct order, and writing them out:

```
std::vector<item> items {
    { "Sub-total:", 17530},
    { "+ Sales Tax:", 1139},
    { "- Discount:", 25},
    { "+ Shipping:", 0, "Ship to: NJ"},
    { "= Total:", 18644.44}
};

 for (auto const & i : items) 
     std::cout << i << "\n";
```

In reality, however, you'd normally start with some actual items (things the customer bought), and all these items would be computed from the things that customer bought:

```
class sale {
    std::vector<item> items;
    const double tax_rate;
public:

    sale(std::initializer_list<item> const& i, double tax_rate = 0.065) 
        : items(i)
        , tax_rate(tax_rate) 
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, sale const& s) {
        item subtotal{ "Subtotal:", 0 };
        item discount{ "- Discount: ", 0 };
        item sales_tax{ "+ Sales Tax:", 0 };
        item shipping{ "+ Shipping:", 0, 0, "Shipping to: NJ" };
        item total{ "= Total:", 0 };

        for (auto const& i : s.items) {
            os << i << "\n";
            subtotal.amount += i.amount;
            discount.amount += i.discount;
            shipping.amount += i.shipping;
            total.amount += i.amount;
            total.amount -= i.discount;
            total.amount += i.shipping;
        }
        sales_tax.amount = subtotal.amount * s.tax_rate;

        os << std::string(40, '-') << '\n';
        os << subtotal << '\n';
        os << sales_tax << '\n';
        os << discount << '\n';
        os << shipping << '\n';
        os << total << '\n';
        return os;
    }
};
```

With that, we'd just list the items they bought, and it would compute the subtotal, tax, etc.

```
int main() { 
    sale items {
        {"Kia Rio", 15390.00, 25},
        {"Stereo", 135.95},
        {"Undercoating", 249.95},
        {"Mud flaps", 124.99},
        { "ADP", 375.25}
    };

    std::cout << items << "\n";
}
```

...which produces output something like this:

```
Kia Rio         $15390.00
Stereo          $  135.95
Undercoating    $  249.95
Mud flaps       $  124.99
ADP             $  375.25
------------------------------
Subtotal:       $16276.14
+ Sales Tax:    $ 1057.95
- Discount:     $   25.00
+ Shipping:     $    0.00 (Shipping to: NJ)
= Total:        $16251.14
```